# SVN - I need a distinct list of file names that have 'something' in the change log

Tags: svn

This gives me the log's where 8013 is in the text

```
svn log -v  url  | find "8013" > changes.txt
```

Is there a way to find the actual files in all of those revisions?

```
svn diff url --summarize -r | find "8013" > changes.txt
```

(Edit: Windows 7 environment)

Comment: And your OS is...?